# BootReceiver doesen't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I know this has been asked tons of times, and there are hundreds of example on internet, but i want to understand what's wrong in my code.
As the title suggest i want to execute some code while the phone turn on, specifically i want to set some Alarms for getting notifications, but that's not relevant now, my problem is that the boot receiver onReceive method is never called apparently

I have the right permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And i've also registered the receiver in the manifest

```
<receiver
  android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
  android:enabled="true" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And I've already created the receiver class

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(pContext,"waiting for debugger",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    //Stuff for the alarms
}
```

}

Can someone explain me what i'm a failing without posting always the same examples that i see everywhere?
I want to know what's wrong in my code, not how it should be done.

**PS:** : I forgot to say that i need to stop the code for debugging the alarm things, but i don't think that's the problem since it doesen't even show the Toast.
**UPDATE:** full manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="feddycapdev.conapo.turnario" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Calendario"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calendario"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingGiorno"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting_giorno" >
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".WebNotificChecker" />
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Sveglia" />
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".NotificaVigilanza" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your entire manifest. In particular, please show the `<activity>` element for your launcher activity, that you must run before your manifest-registered receiver will work.

Comment: And of course you run at least one Activity from your apk from launcher?

Comment: CommonsWare i'm not getting what you are saying, so I should run the activity before the receiver?
But if that's so how can I set notification if the user doesn't open activity?

Comment: you cannot (on API >=11(AFAIK))... one activity should be oppened before reciver starts working ... asked bazillion times

Comment: You mean it should be opened one time for registering receiver, but after first time the receiver should work on every boot, right?
If so that's not the problem since i opened the app before rebooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I should run the activity before the receiver?

Something has to use an explicit `Intent` to start one of your application's components before any manifest-registered receivers will work. For 99% of Android apps, that means that the user has to start your app from the home screen. If your app is serving as a plugin to some other app, you may not need the activity — please discuss this with the developers of the app that would be hosting your plugin.

> how can I set notification if the user doesn't open activity?

You wouldn't set the notification if the user does not open the activity. Your app will only run **when the user lets you run**. If the user chooses not to start your app, or if the user chooses to "Force Stop" your app from within Settings, your manifest-registered receiver will not receive broadcasts.

Comment: So why does facebook receive notification when i boot the phone even if i still didn't opened it, and what's the pourpose in creating a boot receiver if it doesn't work cause the user didn't run the app?

Comment: @FedericoCapece: "what's the pourpose in creating a boot receiver if it doesn't work cause the user didn't run the app?" -- the user has to run the app *once*. At that point, your app is moved out of the so-called "stopped state", and manifest-registered broadcast receivers work. Your app will return to the stopped state if the user uninstalls/reinstalls the app, or if the user clicks "Force Stop" for your app in Settings.

Comment: @FedericoCapece: "i need to stop the code for debugging the alarm things" -- I am skeptical that this will work, as I am skeptical that a `Toast` will work from here. Use `Log` calls to log messages to LogCat.